# Пролистывание страницы в cocos2d (page curl, flip)

Tags: ios, cocos2d

В cocos2d под iOS переворачивание страницы аналогично iBooks для сцены, слоя.

Встроенный эффект не позволяет таскать за пальцем. Нету возможности переворачивать книгу в развороте (как iBooks в горизонтальном развороте).

В каком направлении копать: чистый OpenGL, закрытое API Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу на свой вопрос.
Необходимо естественно использовать OpenGL.
Только надо не забыть включить тест глубины, и отключить отрисовку обратной стороны полигона -- в 2d движке это к сожалению не сделано по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь, что так поздно ответил, но лучше поздно, чем никогда :)
По-моему ответ очевиден: OpenGL. Более того, есть куча малая уже готовых решений (ну право, не думаете же Вы , что эту фишку никто не сделал еще)
Вот то что я нарыл в сети за две минуты с помощью гугля
https://github.com/brow/leaves